# Boto3: is there a way to gracefully interrupt an SQS long poll receive messages request?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

I have successfully created a method that pulls the messages from an SQS queue using long polling, that looks like this:

```py
def dequeue_message(self, callback):
    result = self.queue.receive_messages(MaxNumberOfMessages=1)
    if len(result) != 0:
        body = result[0].body
        try:
            callback(body)
            result.delete()
        except Exception as e:
            print("message not dequeued because an error occurred"
                  "when running callback: " + str(e))
```

But I could not find a way to stop the poll without killing the running Python process (or, obviously, wait for the timeout). What can I do?

Comment: It should return an empty result in 20 seconds or less if no messages arrive at the queue during the long poll. 
 Is that not sufficient?

Comment: Well, it depends. What is specifically the problem? Which frequency is expected to the user interrupt an SQS receive messages request? Maybe for many people wait up to twenty seconds is good enough, but for others, the time spent can be an issue or simply annoying. My question focused on a specific problem, not if the problem is really significant in my specific situation or in most real-world situations.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do this using a flag. Assume that a button should interrupt the polling process. You update a flag as soon as the button is pressed. Then when the polling returns a set of messages, you check the flag, and ignore processing the messages. Don't worry, the messages will still be in the queue. see: [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-receive-delete-message.html)

> Amazon SQS doesn't automatically delete a message after receiving it
>   for you, in case you don't successfully receive the message (for
>   example, the consumers can fail or lose connectivity). To delete a
>   message, you must send a separate request which acknowledges that you
>   no longer need the message because you've successfully received and
>   processed it.

**SAMPLE CODE**:

```
# This is the flag to check for interruptions
is_interrupted = False

# This function will set the flag if an interruption is occurred
def interrupt_polling():
    is_interrupted = True


def dequeue_message(self, callback):
    result = self.queue.receive_messages(MaxNumberOfMessages=1)

    # this is the check that will bypass the Polling process
    # Handle this logic as required
    if is_interrupted:
        # assuming that this needs to be reset to False
        is_interrupted = False
        return

    if len(result) != 0:
        body = result[0].body
        try:
            callback(body)
            result.delete()
        except Exception as e:
            print("message not dequeued because an error occurred"
                  "when running callback: " + str(e))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not address the question. Yes your loop exits eventually once `is_interrupted` has been set, but the question is explicitly about how to break immediately from the blocking call to `receive_messages`, rather than waiting for it to return after timeout.